# About the projective covers of simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, projective-module

I have a question:

> > Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbb K & 0\\ \mathbb K & \mathbb K \end{bmatrix}$. I need to find all of its simple modules and their projective covers.

I know that the simple modules of $A$ are in equivalence with the simple modules of $\frac{A}{Rad(A)}=\begin{bmatrix} \mathbb K & 0\\ 0 & \mathbb K \end{bmatrix}$. Which means that they are simple modules of $\mathbb K^2$ and are identified with the 2 copies of  $\mathbb K$.

But I do not know how to find their projective covers?

Can someone let me know what are those and how can we establish them?

Many thanks!

Comment: Uh, I'm a little baffled. You had [this version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792092/about-the-projective-covers-of-simple-modules) of the question up earlier which had *much* more in the way of context. There doesn't appear to be any motive to delete it, not even negative feedback. This old version of the question was distinctly better. Why did you delete it?  Granted this question is OK too, but you *have* reduced the background information an answerer could potentially use.

Comment: @rschwieb Many thanks for your comment! You are the first one who commented about my question! Thanks! ) I deleted exactly because I didn't receive any feedback! I thought maybe that was because of many information which I put there! Do you know what are the projective covers? Was the previous ones correct? Many thanks!

Comment: I haven’t thought about them in a long time, so I can’t answer confidently. I guess the s Luton is not hard in general for triangular matrix rings

Comment: @rschwieb Many thanks for your comment! Can you help me in finding them please?  (I think they should be the columns and the rows with the associated maps to $\mathbb K$) Thanks!